# How to stop text overflowing background image

Tags: html, css

[image: Text overflowing background image]

How can I prevent the text from overflowing the background image when the page width is decreased, as shown?

I would like the text to always remain relative to the background image.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <section class="sec2">
    <h1 class="h1two">A 44-letter alphabet.</h1>
    <h1 class="h1three">A phonetically consistent language.</h1>
    <h1 class="h1four">A determined teacher you can count on.</h1>
  </section>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.h1two {
  top: 15%;
}

.h1three {
  top: 30%;
}

.h1four {
  top: 45%;
}

.sec2 {
  height: 30vw;
  background-image: url(pictures/output-onlinepngtools.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

Comment: You would need to use `min-height` instead of `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default margin from the `h1` tags.

Then add `line-height: calc(30vw / 3);` this will keep the text fit to the image height up until any line breaks into 2 lines.

You may want to add the `line-height` in the `@media` query

Try the following code bellow:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "LiberationSansRegular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.sec2 {
  height: 30vw;
  background-image: url(pictures/output-onlinepngtools.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

.sec2 h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: calc(30vw / 3);
}
```

```html
<section class="sec2">
  <h1>A 44-letter alphabet.</h1>
  <h1>A phonetically consistent language.</h1>
  <h1>A determined teacher you can count on.</h1>
</section>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the size depending on the screen size:

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).